# Resize content on two divs stacked on top of each other, with height 50% of the page - CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rbntw9fu/) where I have two `div`s stacked on top of each other, and each of them take `50%` of the height of the page.

It worked well so far, but I have decided to add inside each of them a `div` with specific property of `height: 250px`. In this new case, if the height of the screen gets lower than `500px` then the content of the div is hidden.

Is there a way to make the element `<div id="top"></div>` and `<div id="bottom"></div>` to get the height of `div.new-content.centered` and make the entire `body` to overflow? The final result expects `<div id="top"></div>` and `<div id="bottom"></div>` keep their new height and maintain the same position within the page.

Thanks in advance for your replies!

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
}

#top,
#bottom {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50%;
}

#top {
  top: 0;
  background-color: orange;
}

#bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: green;
}

.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.new-content {
  height: 250px;
  width: 25%;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div class="new-content centered red"></div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
  <div class="new-content centered blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think you need to use calc , height: calc(100% - 250px);  ???

Comment: No, because the height of each `div` has to be 50% of the page, but then the total height has to be `500px` and let the whole body overflow while preserving the height of both elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the layout strategy to use `flex`. Also, I center the inner divs by setting margin left and right to `auto`. Please see if this solves the problem.

**UPDATE**

Added solution to calculate the top margin offset of the content blocks using javascript, allowing the blocks to center vertically.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('new-content');

verticalCenterContent = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    var containerHeight = els[i].parentNode.offsetHeight;
    var topOffset = containerHeight / 2 - els[i].offsetHeight / 2;
    if (topOffset > 0) {
      els[i].style.marginTop = topOffset + 'px';
    }
    else {
      els[i].style.marginTop = 0 + 'px';    
    }
  }
}

window.onresize = function(event) {
  verticalCenterContent();
};

verticalCenterContent();
```

```css
body {
  overflow: auto;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

#top,
#bottom {
  flex: 1 1 50vh; /* shorthand for flex-grow flex-shrink flex-basis */
}

#top {
  background-color: orange;
}

#bottom {
  background-color: green;
}

.centered {
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.new-content {
  height: 250px;
  width: 25%;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="top">
    <div class="new-content centered red"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="new-content centered blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jfeferman, is there a way to make the divs with the `new-content` class centered within the parent divs instead of being stacked to the top of the page?

Comment: Thanks, but the height is supposed to be `250px`, and if I change the value it doesn't stay in the center anymore. Any other ideas?

Comment: Yes, good point. I'll investigate further. Would it be ok to use js or you want strictly css?

Comment: No, feel free to also us js if you want :)

Comment: Please check the javascript solution to center the blocks vertically.

Comment: Well, it's not in pure `CSS`, but the result works well. Thanks man!